# Legality of creating an API for a site that has no API (particularly Bing chat)

Tags: api, web-scraping, reverse-engineering, bing-api, eula

I wanted to use the functionality offered by Bing chat (which uses gpt4) in an application of mine without being forced to go through the website. I then analyzed the requests that the site makes when a prompt is sent and discovered the endpoints that the site connects to and would then know how to manually connect to them and make them available to me using session cookies. I wanted to know if it would be legal to create a script that would precisely connect to these links without going through the website.

I saw that there are no official api and I noticed that there are dozens of public repositories on GitHub that do what I had in mind. I looked up user contracts and read that you can't do reverse enegenering with Microsoft products, but I don't know if what I had in mind falls into that category.